# Calling a function within a closure in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
import threading
def func1(a,b):
    def func2():
        t=threading.Thread(target=func3)
        return t
    return func2

func2=func1(a,b)
func2()
```

I have a restriction(the language I'm using is python with some restricted functions) not to use the args parameter for the Thread function instead I want to pass a and b as parameters to func3. How can I do this using closures?

Comment: I think you mean `func2()` and not `func1()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of `lambda` I might look into `functools.partial`.  If that isn't allowed, you could probably do:

```
import threading
def func1(a,b):
    def func2():
        def func4():
            return func3(a,b)
        return threading.Thread(target=func4)
    return func2

func2=func1(a,b)
func2()
```

Comment: This just works perfect for what I'm trying to do..
I have a little confusion here:
How can I catch the thread object returned by the statement
    `threading.Thread(target=func4)`

Comment: Instead of doing `func2()` at the last line, you'd do `thread_object = func2()`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a lambda:

```
t=threading.Thread(target=lambda: func3(a,b))
```

The values of `a` and `b` will be held in a closure, even after `func1` exits.

Instead of a lambda, you can create a named function:

```
def thread_func():
    func3(a,b)
t = threading.Thread(target=thread_func)
```

Comment: I'm afraid lambda usage isn't allowed as well.. Can I do it in any other way?

Comment: @securecoding -- Can you use `functools.partial`?

Comment: Here is what the rule says:
"The args argument has been removed. If you want to call a function  with arguments, then you can define a closure around it".